# Return results based on sequence of criterias in query Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like the results to be in the same sequence as the query. To elaborate more about this, consider the following example. :

I have documents with ID field, which look somewhat like this :

```
{
  {
    "ID": 102,
    "Name": "Mark"
  },
  {
    "ID": 104,
    "Name": "Pete"
  },
  {
    "ID": 101,
    "Name": "Su"
  },
  {
    "ID": 107,
    "Name": "Kate"
  },
  {
    "ID": 106,
    "Name": "Roger"
  }
}
```

And my query is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": 
          {
            "ID": "101"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": 
          {
            "ID": "104"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": 
          {
            "ID": "107"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": 
          {
            "ID": "102"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": 
          {
            "ID": "106"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now I'm expecting the results to be in the same order as the search criteria. i.e :

```
{
    "ID": 101,
    "Name": "Su"
},
{
    "ID": 104,
    "Name": "Pete"
},
{
    "ID": 107,
    "Name": "Kate"
},
{
    "ID": 102,
    "Name": "Mark"
},
{
    "ID": 106,
    "Name": "Roger"
}
```

Been trying to figure out a way to do this. Is it even possible?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you can achieve this kind of scoring mechanism just by using query or filters.

how is the source of those id's coming into the code when your query builder builds the query.Are they coming in the same order as the order you want to sort the document.

If yes, then i would suggest to nourish your query with function score or script based scoring logic. you can use groovy sandbox or mvel.

```
{
  "query": {"filtered": {
    "query": {"function_score": {
      "query": {"match_all": {}},
      "functions": [
        {"script_score": {
          "params": {
            "id_list":[103,105,109,101]
          }, 
          "script": " id_list.length -id_list.indexOf(doc['id'].value)"
        }}
      ]
    }}
  }}
}
```

[Scripting in elasticsearch.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html)

[Function score in elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)

Think about it like feeding a array structure with id contained in the same order you want to return the result as params for script score inside the function score.
After comparing the id of the document from the doc fields assign a score of the Array.size - index to each document.
I think this will pretty much solve your problem.it is not a concrete solution but a work around

Note - carefull my cluster is configured to allow inline script execution and the default script language is configured to javascript. if you follow this approach you may have to look at your cluster configurations as well

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping out!
Although I cant try with this right now, because we decided to avoid the scripts...
However, someone suggested to use multisearch to get it done...If multisearch dosen't work, I will surely try this out...
Again Thanks a ton!

Comment: sure, if multisearch works for few, kindly please update the answer with the working for me and others.Thanks